# JavaScript Date Object Resetting

Tags: javascript, date, timer

So I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out a way to get my timer to reset to 59 seconds every minute in my Pomodoro Timer. Does the date object happen to have a built-in way to count down? Here's my code:

```
'use strict';

//Visual representation of work/break times and counter
let $workDisplay = $("#workNum"),
    $breakDisplay = $("#breakNum"),
    $workMinus = $(".workMinus"),
    $workPlus = $(".workPlus"),
    $breakMinus = $(".breakMinus"),
    $breakPlus = $(".breakPlus"),
    $counter = $("#counter");

//Initialize date object to work with functions (seven 0's to remove default local time)
let time = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

let state = 'off';

//Set time dynamically
let setTime = function(minutes, seconds) {
    minutes = time.setMinutes(minutes);
    seconds = time.setSeconds(seconds);
    return { minutes: minutes, seconds: seconds }
}

//Default value for minutes and seconds (25)
setTime(25 - 1, 59);

let getMinutes = time.getMinutes(setTime.minutes);
let getSeconds = time.getSeconds(setTime.seconds);

$workDisplay.text(getMinutes);
$counter.text(getMinutes);

//Timer states
let toggleTimer = function(newState) {
    displayTime();

    if (state !== 'done') {
        //The ? serves as a toggle (statement ? true value : false value)
        state = newState || (state == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
    }

    if (state == 'off') {
        $counter.text(getMinutes + ":" + getSeconds);
    }
    console.log(state);
}

$counter.on('click', () => toggleTimer());

//Shrink these with an if statement later (check Dustin's DMs on Slack)
$workMinus.on('click', function() {
    getMinutes--;
    console.clear();
    $workDisplay.text(getMinutes);
    $counter.text(getMinutes);
    console.log(getMinutes);
});

$workPlus.on('click', function() {
    getMinutes++;
    console.clear();
    $workDisplay.text(getMinutes);
    $counter.text(getMinutes);
    console.log(getMinutes);
});

//Count down seconds and minutes
let countdownSecond = function() {
    if (state == 'on') {
        //Seconds stuff
        getSeconds--;
        $counter.text(getMinutes + ":" + getSeconds);
    }
}

let countdownMinute = function() {
    if (state == 'on') {
        getMinutes--;
        $counter.text(getMinutes + ":" + getSeconds);
    }
}

//Update time display every minute/second
function displayTime() {
    window.setInterval(countdownSecond, 1000);
    window.setInterval(countdownMinute, 60000)
}

console.log(state);
```

Currently, my timer goes down into the negatives instead of resetting to 59 seconds for a new minute. In fact, it even starts in the negatives! Any tips to help my timer get functioning normally would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You need to research the Date object. It's time value represents milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, setting `new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` creates a date for 1899-12-31T00:00:00.000Z adjusted for your local time zone (the Date object interprets 0 as 1900 and day 0 goes to the last day of the previous month).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a countdown timer and only care about time, use Dates for the epoch and the current time, don't try to use the Date itself for the counter.

So if you want to count down day 5 minutes:

1. Create a date object for the start (this is your epoch)
2. Convert the time interval to seconds (300)
3. Call *setTimeout* about every second (adjusted for the actual elapsed time)
4. The timer function should get the current time by creating a new Date
5. Get the elapsed time as the difference between the epoch and current time
6. Format as either elapsed time or time remaining
7. Stop when you reach zero or the interval (if counting up)

There are lots of countdown timers here, I'm sure you can find one that suits.

Here's one to show the algorithm:

```js
var countDown = (function () {
  var epoch, limitMs, element;
  
  // Return seconds formatted as m:ss
  function toMins(secs) {
    return (secs/60|0) + ':' + ('0'+secs%60).slice(-2)
  }
  
  return function(secs, id) {

    // If first call, set epoch and limit
    if (!epoch) {
   epoch = new Date().getTime();
   limitMs = secs * 1000;
   element = document.getElementById(id);
 }
  
    // Get current time
    var now = new Date();
  
    // Get difference in seconds
    var diff = now - epoch;
 
 // Get time remaining in whole seconds
 var remainSecs = Math.round((limitMs - diff)/1000);
 
 // Set time to next call, as close to next whole second as possible
 var lag = 1000 - (diff%1000);

 // Set default display
    var displayMins = '0:00';
  
    // If haven't reached the end, set the value to display and call again
    if (diff < limitMs) {
      displayMins = toMins(remainSecs);
   setTimeout(countDown, lag);
    }
    element.textContent = displayMins;
  }
}());


countDown(150,'minsDisplay');
```

```html
<div id="minsDisplay"></div>
```